# Prove $\cot a , \cot b, \cot c$ are in AP

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan b =\frac{2\sin a \sin c}{\sin(a+c)}$

I have written the numerator as $\cos (a-c) -\cos (a+c)$

After that I got stuck .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cot{a}+\cot{c}=\frac{\sin(a+c)}{\sin{a}\sin{c}}=\frac{2}{\tan{b}}=2\cot{b}$$

Answer (score 2):

So
$$\cot b=\frac{\sin(a+c)}{2\sin a\sin c}.$$
This looks like a job for the addition formula for the sine.